# pythonリストとイテレータについて

Tags: python, python3, array

下記のブログでリストとイテレータについて書かれているのですが、理解表現があります。

[Pythonのリストはイテレーターでない。わかりやすい（はずの）イテレーターとイテラブルの説明](https://blog.hirokiky.org/entry/2020/02/03/181938)

なぜリスト自身がイテレータの場合一度ループしただけでリストはループ出来なくなってしまうのでしょうか？
この場合のループとは `for in` を指しているのでしょうか？その場合なぜループできなくなるのか分からないです。ブログでは `for in` の内部ではイテレータによる処理が行われているという説明までされています。

> もしリスト自身がイテレーターであれば、1度ループしただけでリストはループできなくなってしまいます（ループの進行状況が管理されるので）。 そのために、リスト自身ではなくリストイテレーターさん（つまりイテレーター）にループの状況を管理してもらっています。Pythonってすごい！

#### 追記

どうやら `for in` にイテレータは渡せるみたいです。

ループでは使用できないという表現がよく分からないです。

> イテレーターは同時にイテラブルでもあります。 なので、イテレーターは for in ... に渡せます。この場合、イテレーターは iter(my_iterator) をすると my_iterator 自身を返します。

Comment: すいません。url修正しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

プログのリンクが不明で, たぶん[ここかな](https://blog.hirokiky.org/entry/2020/02/03/181938)？と

言ってることは, (イテレーターだと) 使い切ってしまうと それ以上は使えない … ですね。
リストの場合

```py
lst = [10,20,30]
for i in lst:
  print(i)
# 10
# 20
# 30

for i in lst:
  print(i)
# 10
# 20
# 30
```

ジェネレーターの場合

```py
def gen1():
  for n in [10,11,12]:
    yield n

g1 = gen1()
for i in g1:
  print(f'1度目 {i}')
# 10
# 11
# 12

for i in g1:
  print(f'2度目 {i}')
# 出力なし
```

ファイルの場合 (試してないけど)

```py
with open('dummydata') as fp:
  for ln in fp:
    print(ln)
  for ln in fp:
    print(ln)
```

Comment: next()したかどうかを保持していて、全てnext()し終えたイテレータは再びイテレート出来ないということでしょうか？

Comment: 上記 `for i in g1` で値を取り出す際に `next()` が呼び出される ==> `gen1`の続きが走り出す ==> `yield`によってもとの処理に戻り, 「次の値」が `i` に入る。データがなくなると `StopIteration` 例外が発生する … という手順です。そこから再度 値を取り出そうとしても, `StopIteration` 例外が発生 ==> メイン側のループは一度も動かない

Comment: `gen1` の処理内, ループの次の処理が存在しないので, そこでおしまいです。`g1 = gen1()` を実行すれば, `g1` によってまた最初から取り出せます

Comment: この場合のメイン側のループはgen1()の処理で使用されるループを指しているんですよね？

Comment: 二度目の `for i in g1:` は, いきなり終了するという意味です。一度目のループで, すでに `g1` から値をすべて取り出し終わり, g1は`StopIteration` 例外が発生している状態なので。(gen1 の処理は最後まで到達し 終了している)

Comment: ファイルの場合も同様, end of file まで到達しているなら, 二度目の `for ln in fp` は, (内部の `print(ln)` を一回も実行することなく)すぐにループは終了する

Comment: とても詳しくありがとうございます。